# cancellation_date in non renewable subscription

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase, non-renewing-subscription

I have developed the

> non renewable Subscription

in my app. i have changed the

> `**[NSBundle appStoreReceiptURL]**` instead of `transactionReceipt` (for Deprecated method)

now I am receiving the receipt like below

```
content: {
  receipt: {
    in_app: [
      {
        is_trial_period: "false",
        original_purchase_date_pst: "2013-10-09 20:55:27 America/Los_Angeles",
        original_purchase_date_ms: "1386571707000",
        original_purchase_date: "2013-10-09 04:55:27 Etc/GMT",
        purchase_date_pst: "2013-10-09 20:55:27 America/Los_Angeles",
        purchase_date_ms: "1386571707000",
        purchase_date: "2013-10-09 04:55:27 Etc/GMT",
        original_transaction_id: "654888452251325",
        transaction_id: "654888452251325",
        product_id: "com.example.myapp.example1”,
        quantity: "1"
      }
    ],
    original_application_version: "1.0",
    original_purchase_date_pst: "2013-10-09 20:55:27 America/Los_Angeles",
    original_purchase_date_ms: "1386569706000",
    original_purchase_date: "2013-10-09 04:55:27 Etc/GMT",
    request_date_pst: "2013-10-09 20:55:27 America/Los_Angeles",
    request_date_ms: "1386571710087",
    request_date: "2013-10-09 04:55:27 Etc/GMT",
    download_id: 215425636588954,
    application_version: "1.0",
    bundle_id: "com.example.myapp”,
    adam_id: 654225311,
    receipt_type: "Sandbox"
  },
  environment: "Sandbox",
  status: 0
}
```

if my customer request for refund means , the receipt will contain the `cancellation_date` . my question is, whether the `

> cancellation_date

` will be display within the

> `receipt` or `in_app`

Anyone please help me to resolve my problem.  Thanks advance.

Comment: It is in the in_app receipt https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html

Comment: will it be come unde r the in_app field or receipt field?

Comment: As I said, in_app. It has to be since individual subscription purchases can be cancelled.